# How to validate number having different unit and range by regex

Tags: regex

How can I achieve below validation with regular expression.

range 1:  `1 to 200 pt`
range 2:  `0.05 to 7 cm`

**Accept:**

```
1.5pt
1pt
2cm
3.5cm
```

**Reject:**

```
0pt
0.01cm
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
^(?:(?:(?:200|(?:(?:[1-9]\d?)|(?:1\d{0,2}))(?:\.\d+)?)pt)|(?:(?:7|(?:[1-6](?:\.\d+)?)|(?:0\.(?:0[5-9]|[1-9])(?:\d+)?))cm))$
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0dHX3z/2/)

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what i want. have a good day to you.